# Copy data using Azure Devops Pipeline to a storage account with no public network acces

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-storage

I'm trying to backup a Azure DevOps repo using the following guide: https://charbelnemnom.com/how-to-backup-azure-devops-git-repositories/

My YAML-File is as follows:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  branches:
   include:
     - '*'
stages: 
- stage: _default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: git clone --mirror https://PATTokenXXXX@dev.azure.com/btc-cloud/test/_git/testrepo
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
       rootFolderorFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testrepo.git
       includeRootFolder: true
       archiveType: zip
       archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Backup.zip
    - task: AzureFileCopy@3
      displayName: AzureBlob File Copy
      inputs:
        SourcePath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Backup.zip
        azureSubscription: test backup of devops repo
        Destination: AzureBlob
        storage: 'storageaccountname'
        ContainerName: 'devopsbackup'
        BlobPrefix: 'az-devops-repo-backup'
```

The Pipeline is working fine as long as the `Public Network Access` is on `Enabled from all networks`. But when I disable public network access, the Pipeline doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to implement the pipeline to use a private Network, maybe through a private endpoint? But since I don't see a way how to add the DevOps pipeline to a private network, I'm kind of lost how to make the pipeline work when the storage account has public network access disabled. Does someone maybe know how to do it or know an alternative way to backup Azure DevOps projects?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run agent on machine that has access to your private network.
Usually this can be achieved by using self-hosted agents (installed on VM, VMSS or on container instance) with access to your private network.

If you use Azure DevOps you may add new pool from organization settings.

Default Azure agents use public access and won't be able to access storage account with access limited only to private network.

More details you may find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: it worked, I had to create a private endpoint with a private dns-zone

Comment: @AzUser1 Could you perhaps post an answer to walk through how you got it working? Nothing here explains private endpoints in enough detail for people to follow if they're having the same issue.

Comment: As far as I can remember I had to use a Private DNS Zone in Azure to keep the network access private. In order to do this, the Storage Account is connected with the Private DNS Zone through a private endpoint. Then I had to create a VM with the self-hosted devops agent that has to be connected to the private DNS Zone, too. This was also through a private Endpoint that was connected to the VM.